# Modifying a Join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following Query in an SQL Server stored procedure

```
SELECT SZ_SK FROM tbl_Class CC
INNER JOIN tbl_Location LR ON CC.LCTN_RSTN = LR.LCTN_RSTN
WHERE LR.LCTN_RSTN = ISNULL(@Location,LR.LCTN_RSTN)
```

I have a problem though, I realized that in the `tbl_Class` the `LCTN_RSTN` value could be `NULL`, `tbl_Location` doesn't have a `NULL` field. This is an issue since if `@Location = NULL` then I want fields where `CC.LCTN_RSTN= NULL` to show up.  Any way I can do that? (`SZ_SK` only exists in `tbl_Class`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming LCTN_RSTN is a string and you don't use empty strings anywhere

```
SELECT SZ_SK FROM tbl_Class CC
INNER JOIN tbl_Location LR ON ISNULL(CC.LCTN_RSTN, '') = ISNULL(LR.LCTN_RSTN, '')
WHERE LR.LCTN_RSTN = ISNULL(@Location,LR.LCTN_RSTN)
```

Would join the nulls. NULL != NULL, but converting to empty strings, '' = ''

The basic technique here is to use a sentinel value outside your actual range. If LCTN_RSTN is IDENTITY(1,1), for example, use -1 as your default for nulls.

Comment: Great, not quite what I used but it put me on the right track since I realized I could do something like this which worked for me: `ISNULL(CC.LCTN_RSTN, @NoneValue) = LR.LCTN_RSTN`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT SZ_SK FROM tbl_Class CC
INNER JOIN tbl_Location LR 
     ON coalesce(CC.LCTN_RSTN,'') = coalesce(LR.LCTN_RSTN,'')
WHERE (@Location is null) or (coalesce(LR.LCTN_RSTN,'') = @Location)
```